# What's the time complexity of this function?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I'm just trying to figure out what's the time complexity for the following function, I'm not sure if it's `O(logn)` or `O(nlogn)`.

Thanks in advance for the help! :)

**PD:** I'll appreciate if you can tell me the why of your response

```
def max_unimodal(arr):
  
  if len(arr) == 1:
    return arr[0]
  elif len(arr) == 2:
    return max(arr[0], arr[1])
  
  mid = len(arr) // 2
  
  max_left = max_unimodal(arr[:mid])
  max_right = max_unimodal(arr[mid:])

  return max(max_left, max_right)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recurrence is `T(n) = 2T(N/2) +O(1)`. It should be obvious that `T(N) = O(N)`, either by a master theorem (which is overkill in this case), or by a simple expansion:

```
T(N) = 2T(N/2) + c +
       2(2T(N/4) + c) + c = 4T(N/4) + 3c = 
       4(2T(N/8) + c) + 3c = 8T(N/8) + 7c =
       ....
       = 2^kT(N/2^k) + 2^(k-1) c
```

all the way until `2^k` is approximately `N`, giving

```
T(N) = (T(1) + c/2) * N
```

Edit: To address the concern in the comment:

The above analysis assumed list view passing. In the literal implementation with the Python list slices has much worse complexity. List slicing itself is `O(n)`, and the recurrence become `T(N) = 2T(N/2) +O(N)`. Try to prove that in this case the result is <strike>`O(N^2)`</strike> `O(N log N)` (I don't know what I was thinking), using the same method.

Comment: The recurrence is `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(n)`, because list slicing is not done in constant time.

Comment: @kaya3 Since the language is not specified, I took the liberty to assume reference (or list view) passing. Probably should mention it in the answer.

Comment: The complexity is `O(n log n)`, not `O(n^2)`. It is the same recurrence relation as merge sort, for example.